# Lexer tokenizing SKIP and NEWLINE values. How to hide them?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, lexer, dot

My lexer code below generates both "SKIP" and "NEWLINE" values where it is supposed to hide them. Could someone please tell me what should I do to hide them?

```
        tok_regex = '|'.join('(?P<%s>%s)' % pair for pair in token_specification)
        get_token = re.compile(tok_regex, re.DOTALL).match
        mo = get_token(self.input, self.p)

        self.p = mo.end()

        if self.p >= len(self.input):
            self.c = "EOF"
        else:
            if mo is not None:
                self.c = mo.lastgroup
                self.val = mo.group(self.c)
                if self.c == 'NEWLINE':
                    self.line += 1

    def next_token(self):

        keywords = {'digraph', 'subgraph', 'node', 'edge', 'strict', 'graph'}
        self.tokenize()
        if self.c != 'SKIP' and self.c != "NEWLINE":

            if self.c == 'ID' and self.val in keywords:
                self.c = self.val
        return TokenTypes.Token(self.c, self.val)
        # if self.p != len(self.input):
        #    raise RuntimeError('Unexpected character %r on line %d' %(self.input[self.p], self.line))

def main():
    statements = '''
        digraph G {
            main [shape=box]; 
        }
    '''
    lexer = Lexer(statements)
    t = lexer.next_token()
    i = 0
    while (t.typ != "EOF"):
        i += 1
        print(t)
        t = lexer.next_token()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

I am trying to generate an abstract syntax tree for the dot grammar by importing the tokens from the above lexer. But the unwanted SKIP and NEWLINE tokens are creating the trouble.

Here is an example input:

```
digraph G { main [shape=box]; }
```

Which produces the output:

```
NEWLINE digraph SKIP ID SKIP LBRACE NEWLINE ID SKIP LBRACKET ID EQUAL ID RBRACKET END SKIP NEWLINE SKIP RBRACE
```

But it should output:

```
digraph ID LBRACE ID LBRACKET ID EQUAL ID RBRACKET END RBRACE
```

Comment: Can you give an example input, incorrect output, and desired output?

Comment: input: """digraph G {
         main [shape=box]; 
      }""" . Incorrect Output: NEWLINE digraph SKIP ID SKIP LBRACE NEWLINE ID SKIP LBRACKET ID EQUAL ID RBRACKET END SKIP NEWLINE SKIP RBRACE. Desired Output:  digraph ID LBRACE ID LBRACKET ID EQUAL ID RBRACKET END RBRACE

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to change the `next_token()` method to parse another token if `NEWLINE` or `SKIP` is encountered. Example:

```
def next_token(self):
    keywords = {'digraph', 'subgraph', 'node', 'edge', 'strict', 'graph'}

    # Parse next token.
    self.tokenize()
    while self.c == "SKIP" or self.c == "NEWLINE":
        # Discard this token and parse another token.
        self.tokenize()

    if self.c == 'ID' and self.val in keywords:
        self.c = self.val

    return TokenTypes.Token(self.c, self.val)
    # if self.p != len(self.input):
    #    raise RuntimeError('Unexpected character %r on line %d' %(self.input[self.p], self.line))
```